# Adding Numbers Entered by for-loop

Tags: java

My objective is to add numbers, entered by the user, using a for-loop .

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
class Student {
    public static void main (String args[]){
    int mks=0, i=0 ,percnt=0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter Marks Of Student ");      

            for (i=0;i<=4;i++){
            mks= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            mks=mks+i;
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {}
        percnt=mks/5;

        System.out.println("GRAND TOTAL = "+mks+ " PERCENTAGE"+percnt);
    }
}
```

I am getting the marks entered last + 4 with this code.

Comment: if this is homework then please add the homework tag

Comment: @pb2q its not its a doubt molded into a Ques

Comment: @Lion it wont matter it would just take 1 less entry

Answer (score 1):

> "my objective is to add the numbers entered by the user using for
>   loop"

You need to accumulate each integer entered by the user:

```
mks += Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

> "i m getting marks entered last + 4 with this code"

This is because your code:

```
mks= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  // Get the integer the user entered
mks=mks+i;        // Add i (which in the case of the last iteration is 4)
```

is setting the value of `mks` everytime the loop restarts.
Also, if you are trying to count all of the numbers the user enters, there is no need to add the loop counter `i` to the accumulator variable `mks`

Comment: mks += Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

line contain error illegal start of expression

Comment: @user1458650: Is this line placed in the for loop within the correct curly braces?

Comment: yes it is placed in the for loop within the correct curly braces

Comment: @user1458650: The code compiles and runs as expected for me. You may want to double check your use of curly braces. `Illegal start of expression` is generally due to improper use of curly braces and/or attempting to declare a method inside another method.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the "mks= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());" is called, it overwrites the previous values of mks. So the last time you run it, you get the last line entered +4 (the value of i at the time).

If you're wanting to sum the value of all the loaded marks, you should make a new variable that doesn't get overwritten. Or alternatively, you could do

```
mrks = mrks + Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()) + i
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reinitializing your accumulator (mks) variable with each loop iteration.

You need to define it once, outside of the loop, with value of zero, then add to it with each loop iteration.

Also, get rid of  `mks=mks+i`

Lastly, catching Exceptions and ignoring them doesn't do you any good. You should at least display an error message when there is an exception. Otherwise, just declare the exception in a `throws` clause, and let it propagate (i.e. let it terminate the program).

Comment: if i define it once outside the loop it wont fetch multiple values from user

Comment: @user1458650: Declare it outside of the loop. But accumulate within.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like.

```
int mks=0, i=0 ,percnt=0;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
try {
    System.out.println("Enter Marks Of Student ");

for (i=0;i<=4;i++){
    mks+=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())+i;
    //mks=mks+i;
}
}catch (Exception e) {}
percnt=mks/5;
System.out.println("GRAND TOTAL = "+mks+ " PERCENTAGE"+percnt);
```

Comment: Apart from this, I'm not sure why you're adding `i` to `mks`. Of course, it's working correctly as specified. There is no calculation problem. I think, there is no such need to add `i` to `mks`.

Comment: This statement `mks+=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())+i;` seems to be something like this `mks+=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());`, removing `i`.

Comment: If it's useful to you, you should consider marking it as your [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer as StackOverflow is a reputation site.